# PyQt5 - How to connect Close Key (red x) to a function

Tags: python, pyqt, qt5, pyqt5

I am trying to connect the `close key (red x)` to a function (message box). What I tried so far doesn't work; my code will freeze when I click the `close key (red x)`. No error message.

Here is my code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox 
class Ui_MainWindow(QMainWindow):
   def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
      MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
      MainWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
      MainWindow.resize(987, 746)
      MainWindow.setMinimumSize(567, 456)
      MainWindow.setMaximumSize(987, 746)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(9)
      MainWindow.setFont(font)
      self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
      QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

   def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
      _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
      MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", ""))

   def Exit(self):
      reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are You Sure to Quit?', QMessageBox.No| QMessageBox.Yes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   app.aboutToQuit.connect(Ui_MainWindow.Exit)
   MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
   MainWindow.show()
   Ui = Ui_MainWindow()
   Ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't understand why would you create a class Ui_MainWindow but here is an example of how I would do what you're trying to do:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QMessageBox


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

   def __init__(self):
      super().__init__()
      self.setupUI()

   def setupUI(self):
      self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
      self.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
      self.resize(987, 746)
      self.setMinimumSize(567, 456)
      self.setMaximumSize(987, 746)
      font = QtGui.QFont()
      font.setPointSize(9)
      self.setFont(font)


   def closeEvent(self, event):
      reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Quit', 'Are You Sure to Quit?', QMessageBox.No | QMessageBox.Yes)
      if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
         event.accept()
      else:
         event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":
   import sys
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   mw = MainWindow()
   mw.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. My code was generated by Qt Designer. This is the reason for the `Ui_MainWindow`.  I tried to insert the `__init__` constructor for the class, from your answer, with the `super().__init__()`, but it didn’t fully solve my problem. My code doesn’t freeze now, but it still doesn’t connect to the message box, it just exits.

Comment: It's simple, 2 things: -You must have the closeEvent function in your class. -2nd thing, the window which is showed is MainWindow but the class you're trying to handle is Ui_MainWindow.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I can't apply your answer to my code, it doesn't seem to work.  Can you please show the way to apply your solution to my actual code in my original post without adding the `def __init__(self):`?

Comment: If the code you show here is all you have then you can just copy paste my code. It works for me (window 10, python 3.6)

Comment: Obviously, the code I posted is not all I have. As you can see, it's an empty window. Clearly, no one  would write a code only for an empty window. What I posted is, what I hope to be, a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: actually your answer is right, your solution is working, it was my bad, i just forgot to remove a line of code when i was testing it.